# How to force user agent on mobile browser

Tags: php, http, user-agent

Im integrating Magento and Expression Engine. EE is pulling header and footer from Magento. And Magento has a mobile theme for specific agents but EE does not. So I wanna force mobile users to load desktop version of the site so the approach I took was to set desktop user agent in the header. Here were a few methods I've tried. However, things aren't working out. Is there a better solution?

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36');
```

and

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setHeaders(array('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; PalmOS 3.0) EudoraWeb 2'));
```

and

```
ini_set('user_agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
```

Comment: I don't think your code will work as expected. The first example is setting a `cURL` option. The second is setting a `HttpRequest` which is not part of `cURL`. The third is setting a server side configuration file. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I just updated the description. How that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is displaying a distinct version of itself to mobile users, what you have to do is find where this content switching is happening and make it stop doing so. According to what you said, messing around with cURL and whatnot won't change a thing.